# Submit form info to Company's Email

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-email, email-attachments

So I've created a form and I was trying to do it's validation (once someone fills it and press the 'sent' button, it's content should be sentend to the company's email), but I actually don't know how to do it.

I've searched and I've tried some codes, but nothing actualy happens. 
I've tried the `<form action="mailto:companysemail" method="post" enctype="text/plain">` but all it did was open the email app with a new blank email.
How can I do it? Is there any other way?

Also, the attach CV (in my case) will work? (It's my first time with attach)

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

section {
  height: calc(90% - 50px);
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li.active a {
  background-color: #6dafad;
  /* cor de fundo do que está seleccionado */
  color: #fff;
  /* cor do texto do que está seleccionado */
  border-radius: 2rem;
  /* adiciona as arestas redondas */
  margin: 0 0.25em;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  /* altera a cor de texto do cabeçalho */
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #d4e1e3;
  /* altera a cor de texto do cabeçalho quando se passa com o rato por cima */
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,

/* altera a cor de fundo do elemento activo quando se passa por cima */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #d4e1e3;
  background-color: #6dafad;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,

/* altera a cor de fundo do elemento activo quando se abre o dropdown */

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  color: #d4e1e3;
  background-color: #6dafad;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  /* adiciona as arestas redondas */
  margin: 0 0.25em;
}

.affix {
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: padding 0.2s linear;
  transition: padding 0.2s linear;
}

.affix-top {
  padding-top: 15px;
  /* altura entre texto e topo cabeçalho */
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  /* altura entre texto e base cabeçalho */
  -webkit-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: padding 0.5s linear;
  transition: padding 0.5s linear;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  /* se não estiver, parte do logo - zona branca - fica comida -> esquerda */
  max-height: 50px;
  /* altura maxima do logotipo */
}


/* fim cabeçalho */


/* inicio corpo */

body {
  color: #666;
  font: 300 15px/15px Roboto, Arial, Helvetica;
  background-color: #f5f7f7;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.spacer {
  padding: 5em;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
}

h1 {
  font: 700 3em Raleway, Arial, Helvetica;
  padding: 5em 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  font: 700 1.5em Raleway, Arial, Helvetica;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  color: #97CACA;
}

h3 {
  font: 700 1.25em Raleway, Arial, Helvetica;
  margin: 0.5em 0;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  margin-bottom: 1.7em;
}

p {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  margin-bottom: 1.7em;
}

.service {
  padding: 0 10em 2em 10em;
  color: #fff;
}

.service p {
  color: #EFACC2;
  font-size: 0.90em;
  margin: 0;
}

.social a {
  margin-right: 1em;
}


/* Formulario*/

input[type="text"]:focus,
textarea:focus,
textarea.form-control:focus {
  outline: 0;
  background: #fff;
  /* fundo da area de escrita - seleccionado */
  border: 3px solid #d1e6c5;
  /* borda da area de escrita - seleccionado */
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder,
textarea:-moz-placeholder,
textarea.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #9d9892;
}

input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder,
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder,
textarea.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #9d9892;
}

input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder,
textarea.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #9d9892;
}

label {
  font-weight: 400;
}

strong {
  font-weight: 600;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: #6dafad;
  text-decoration: none;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -ms-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}

h1,
h2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 42px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #615c58;
  line-height: 30px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background: #d1e6c5;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
  background: #6dafad;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: none;
}


/* fundo do texto seleccionado */


/***** Top content *****/

.top-content h1 {
  color: #fff;
}

.top-content .description {
  margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.top-content .description a {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #fff;
}

.top-content .description a:hover,
.top-content .description a:focus {
  border: 0;
}

.top-content .top-big-link {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.form-box {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.form-top {
  padding: 25px 25px 15px 25px;
  background: #d1e6c5;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  /* cantos redondos, area do formulario - texto */
}

.form-top h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.form-bottom {
  padding: 25px 25px 30px 25px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #d1e6c5;
  /* espessura do formulario */
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  /* cantos redondos, area do formulario */
}

.form-bottom form textarea {
  height: 100px;
}

.form-bottom form .input-error {
  border-color: #d05a4e;
}


/***** Media queries *****/

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .inner-bg {
    padding: 40px 0 110px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <!--/ INICIO cabeçalho <-->
  <div id="wrap">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-light navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #97CACA; color: #fff; border-color: transparent;" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand navbar-fixed-top" href="#"><img class="img-responsive logo" width="300" height="300" src="https://preview.ibb.co/gAXWf7/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="sobre-nos.html">Sobre Nós</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Serviços <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="criancas.html">Bebés e Crianças</a></li>
                <li><a href="adultos.html">Adultos e Séniores</a></li>
                <li><a href="empresas.html">Empresas</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="jobs.html">Venha trabalhar conosco!</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contactos</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/ FIM cabeçalho <-->

  <!--/ INICIO corpo <-->

  <div class="top-content">
    <div class="inner-bg">
      <div class="contentor">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box">
            <div class="form-top">
              <h2>Venha trabalhar conosco!</h2>
              <p>A Algarve's Sitters é uma empresa portuguesa, sediada na região do Algarve, que atua com bebés, crianças, adultos e séniores. Distingue-se pela elevada qualidade dos serviços que presta e por contar com colaboradores qualificados e especializados,
                cuidadosamente selecionados em função da sua educação, valores e experiência.</p>
              <p>Se quiser integrar esta equipa, preencha por favor o formulário abaixo apresentado. Se tiver as qualificações e o perfil adequado, entraremos em contacto consigo.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-bottom">
              <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                  <label for="name">Nome</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" maxlength="50">
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                  <label for="name">Sobrenome</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" maxlength="50">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" maxlength="50">
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                  <label for="phone">Contacto</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required maxlength="50">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                  <label for="residencia">Área de residência/ Concelho</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="residencia" name="residencia" maxlength="100">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
                  <label for="experiencia">Experiência profissional</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="experiencia" name="experiencia" required maxlength="100">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                  <label for="conhecimento">Como tomou conhecimento da Algarve's Sitters?</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="conhecimento" name="conhecimento" required maxlength="300">
                </div>
              </div>

              <fieldset class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <label class="col-sm-12">Áreas de trabalho a que se candidata</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="bebes" value="option1">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">Bebés e Crianças</label>
                      <br>
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="adultos" value="option2">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2">Adultos e Séniores</label>
                      <br>
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="empresas" value="option3">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">Empresas</label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                  <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Curriculum Vitæ</label>
                  <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="cv" name="cv" required maxlength="100">
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                  <label for="name">Comentário adicional</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="comentario" name="comentario" placeholder="A sua mensagem aqui..." maxlength="6000" rows="5"></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block" style="background-color: #d1e6c5;" id="btnContactUs">Post It! </button>
                </div>
              </div>

              <label class="checkbox-inline" for="checkboxes-1">
                         <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="termos" value="1" required="required">Li e aceito os <a href="#" target="blank">Termos e Condições</a>
                        </label>

              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This hasn't been a good idea/possible for some time now...

Comment: It might be better to go with a server side script like PHP.